# Image in GridView ASP

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view in which in one column I want to display images. I have image URL stored in the database.I want the the gridview to dynamically bind the ImageField with the url from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image ID="ProductImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ProductImagePath") %>'/>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Or this

```
<asp:ImageField HeaderText="Image" DataImageUrlField="ProductImagePath"/>
```